# Pattern matching compile error in Chicken compiler but not in Chicken interpreter

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I am trying to get pattern matching working, but I can only get it working in the Chicken interpreter - not the compiler.

Here is an example of it in the interpreter:

```
CHICKEN
(c) 2008-2015, The CHICKEN Team
(c) 2000-2007, Felix L. Winkelmann
Version 4.10.0 (rev b259631)
freebsd-unix-clang-x86-64 [ 64bit manyargs dload ptables ]
compiled 2015-08-04 on yves.more-magic.net (Linux)

#;1> (use matchable)
; loading /usr/local/lib/chicken/7/matchable.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/lib/chicken/7/chicken.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/lib/chicken/7/lolevel.import.so ...
; loading /usr/local/lib/chicken/7/matchable.so ...
#;2> (match '((1 2) (3 4)) [(a . b) b] [() 0])
((3 4))
#;3>
```

Here is the compiled version:

```
(declare (uses matchable))

(match '((1 2) (3 4))
       [(a . b) b]
       [() 0])
```

This fails (`csc src/test.scm`):

```
Syntax error: (src/test.scm:4) - malformed expression: (a . b)
inside expression `(match ...)'


Expansion history:

<syntax>          (##core#begin (match (quote ((1 2) (3 4))) ((a . b) b) (() 0)))
<syntax>          (match (quote ((1 2) (3 4))) ((a . b) b) (() 0))
<syntax>          (quote ((1 2) (3 4)))
<syntax>          (##core#quote ((1 2) (3 4)))
<syntax>          ((a . b) b)
<syntax>          (##core#let ((g0 (a . b))) (g0 b))
<syntax>          (a . b)       <--
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to load the import library at compile time.  The `declare` statement simply says that it depends on `matchable` at runtime.

Simply do the same you did in the interpreter: `(use matchable)` instead of `(declare (uses matchable))`.

Comment: Thank you! Any chance you could go into a little more detail? Where is the `declare` statement actually supposed to be used? Am I supposed to include both `(declare (uses matchable))` and `(use matchable)` in a file?

Comment: The `(uses matchable)` indicates that it has a compile-time dependency on the `matchable` unit.  Compilation units are mostly useful when doing static linking (separate compilation).  If you want dynamic linking, you wouldn't use `declare` at all, but only `(use ...)`.  Use will load the extension at run-time, and import the identifiers of the corresponding module as well.

Comment: This will be considerably simplified in CHICKEN 5. It's a frequent source of frustration for newbies, which is mostly due to historical reasons (modules are a more recent addition, and compilation units are not the most common thing people would use, but they're still given a lot of prominence in the manual because support for separate compilation is an important design goal of CHICKEN, as it also makes cross-compilation possible).

Comment: I'm still confused. But this is good info. And I'm glad to hear things are being cleaned up or perhaps just documented more clearly.